# ubuntu 12.10 - issues with installing php 5.3

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am running ubuntu 12.10 OS . I have recently installed the same on my system . Installation of apache2 seemed fine . But when i tried installing php 5.3 using a set of commands as below , i got the a bunch of issues to face .

```
    sudo -i
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.28.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.28.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.28
./configure
make
make install
```

As i run the command :

```
./configure
```

I get the below error :

```
checking libxml2 install dir... no
checking for xml2-config path... /usr/bin/xml2-config
checking whether libxml build works... no
configure: error: build test failed.  Please check the config.log for details.
```

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you install it from sources at first place? Anything particularly wrong with `apt-get` and `.deb` packages?

Comment: probably some dependency issue. try with package manager like apt-get.

Comment: i do not get any errors as such . I am asking for suggestions . A counter question does not really help.

Comment: i want to install php5.3.28 in particular because i want to run the older version of cakephp as per the requirements.

Comment: @user3790233: cakephp requires 5.3.28? What is its version requirements?

Comment: @zerkms - i said 'older versions of cakephp' . The version of cakephp that i want to use is 1.2.7 which is pretty old and it doesn't run on the latest php versions supposedly due to the obsolete functions which are being used by the framework.

Comment: @user3790233: what version of **PHP** does it require?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this once**.

This will downgrade your php version.

Download shell script from this [link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/php5_4_downgrade_5.3.sh). once you have that **.sh** downloaded file. you need to change the permission using this command

```
sudo chmod 755 php5_4_downgrade_5.3.sh
```

Next you can run the script using this command

```
sudo sh php5_4_downgrade_5.3.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command only..

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

read this https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/php5.html

**Update:**

For specific php version try this commands.

```
sudo apt-get install php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-cli=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-common=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 libapache2-mod-php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
sudo apt-get install php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-cli=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-common=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 libapache2-mod-php5=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
sudo apt-get install php-pear=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-curl=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-gd=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-intl=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-mysql=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-pspell=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-recode=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-snmp=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-sqlite=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-tidy=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-xmlrpc=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 php5-xsl=5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
```

have a look at this answer. https://askubuntu.com/a/220086/199645

Comment: This installs the latest version of php , which i do not want. I want php 5.3 in particular.

Answer (score 0):

try this command only

```
$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```