# how to install php 5.3.10 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu and PHP i need install PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.I tried 
several ways

```
1.apt-get install php5 (it is installing php 5.5.9 it is not version what i need )

2.sudo -i

wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.10.tar.bz2

tar -xvf php-5.3.10.tar.bz2

cd php-5.3.10

./configure

make
make install
```

(when it run "make" command it is given error)

```
3.sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php5
```

(it is also not working for me )

any can tell how install php 5.3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 step by step

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [ubuntu 12.10 - issues with installing php 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859409/ubuntu-12-10-issues-with-installing-php-5-3)

Comment: It tried .but doesn't work.

Comment: first search to remove  php and apache from your system, then search google for installing lamp on ubuntu...

Comment: yes i did it then i  it is installed sucess.but probles is avalabal;e version LAMP Stack 5.3.29-0 (64-bit)..i need 5.3.10

Comment: so what is the problem with that, why you want that specific version to be installed, 5.3.29 is also a stable version and supports all the things that are supported in lower version then that

Comment: I have work application developed by php 5.3.10..actualy it is front end php backend java

Comment: Thank you i sorted..helped your link

Answer (score 1):

This will install  php 5.3.10 version.on Ubuntu  14.04

Download shell script from this [link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/images/php5_4_downgrade_5.3.sh). once you have that .sh downloaded file. you need to change the permission using this command

```
sudo chmod 755 php5_4_downgrade_5.3.sh
```

Next you can run the script using this command

```
sudo sh php5_4_downgrade_5.3.sh
```

Comment: where is the link please?

Comment: ```W: Failed to fetch http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-backports/multiverse/source/Sources: 404  Not Found [IP: 195.85.215.252 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache```...

Comment: This completely broke my apache on 14.04.